# Linux Music Player that shows both waveform and moodbar

Tags: linux, music

In the [Clementine](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine) music player you can show [moodbars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moodbar), which is a neat feature to visualize the mood of a song.

[image]

In [Audacity](https://github.com/audacity/audacity) you can see the waveform of a song, which is similarly useful.

[image]

Is there a music player for Linux that can do both at the same time?